# OS X Alternative to Visual Studio Cloud Explorer

Tags: macos, visual-studio, azure, azure-storage, visual-studio-code

I'm in the process of seeing how far I can go using Visual Studio Code on a MacBook while developing a .NET API on Azure. Currently I use VMWare Fusion /Windows 10/Visual Studio 2015 on the Mac but as good as VMWare Fusion is I'd sure like to be able to code directly from OS X (El Capitan) using the .NET Core / Visual Studio Code stuff.

So my question is has anyone found an alternative to the Visual Studio Cloud Explorer panel? Something that will let me see the contents of Azure queues/tables etc.

Comment: Is using tools outside of Visual Studio Code an option?

Comment: @GauravMantri Oh yes, absolutely; I assumed it would be outside of VSCode. A OS X native app is what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question will most likely be closed as it is asking for tool recommendation but I still want to provide an answer.

There are a few options available from Microsoft:

- **Cross Platform Azure Storage Explorer** (http://storageexplorer.com): Though currently it only support blobs but based on their release notes, support for tables and queues is coming very soon. So you may want to keep in eye out.
- **Azure CLI Tools** (https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/tree/dev/lib/commands/storage): Though not a UI tool but if you're comfortable managing through a command line interface, you may want to check it out.

Comment: I guess you're right; be kinda useful to have a site that is explicitly for this kind of question

Comment: MSDN Forums would be the right place for this kind of question IMHO.